# Video recording without user interaction

Tags: video, interaction, video-recording

I want to record video with new iPhone SDK available on 3GS without user interaction. I went through UIImagePickerController and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate class reference. I also tried to look at the sample code provided by Apple.

Is it possible to record video without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not expect to find such access in the iPhone SDK - potential to record video without the user knowing seems too sneaky.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Yeah that's true but my idea is to give user some more features that are not available with current video recording.